# How to use zip.js in React

Tags: reactjs, zip.js

I'm using [zip.js](http://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/) to unzip .zip file. I know this library is useful and powerful, but I want to use it in React. The installation instruction is just for the general use. So how can I import the lib so that I can use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you include it as mentioned in the documentation -

it should be available globally through the window.zip object, which you can access anywhere in a react application.